# Why Stream.of(1, 2, 3).max(Comparator::comparingInt) can not be compiled?

Tags: java

```
1: Stream.of(1, 2, 3).max(Comparator::comparingInt)
2: Stream.of(1, 2, 3).max(Integer::compare)
```

why the second line can be used, but the first way can not ?

Comment: Because `comparingInt` takes a `ToIntFunction` parameter: `Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i)` would work.

Comment: `Stream.of(...)` works on objects, not primitives. Did you maybe mean to use `IntStream.of(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream.max()` requires a `Comparator` instance. A method reference that fits this interface must have two arguments and return an `int`.

`Integer`'s `compare` method fits these requirements.

`Comparator`'s `comparingInt` does not.

`comparingInt` returns a `Comparator`, so if you want to use it with `Stream.max()`, you have to execute it instead of passing a method reference referring to it.

For example, the following will work:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).max(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> i));
```

or

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).max(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

In both cases, you have to pass a `ToIntFunction` to `comparingInt` (i.e. a function that accepts an object and returns an `int`).

Answer (score 0):

`Comparator::comparingInt` is a *method reference* to the method:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)
```

So you can only pass a `Comparator::comparingInt` to methods that accept a functional interface with a signature similar to

```
Function<ToIntFunction<T>, Comparator<T>>
```

which `Stream.max` is not.

You most likely wanted to *call* the method `comparingInt`, instead of using a method reference:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3).max(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x))
```

---

`Integer::compare` on the other hand is a method reference to the method:

```
public static int compare(int x, int y)
```

Which matches the signature of the functional interface that `max` needs - `Comparator<Integer>`.